# Is there a way to detect the utilized power capacity of a circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, heat

I note that some EVSE (EV chargers) are variable amperage. Some allow you to set the amperage you wish them to draw, and some "auto detect" the amperage to draw. After reading the fine print, the "auto detect" feature is based on the dongle with the plug. So, if you change the dongle from a NEMA 14-50 to a NEMA 5-15, the EVSE detects that the plug is only capable of a continuous 12A, so it only draws that much.

This all works fine if the receptacle is on a dedicated circuit and a DIYer didn't put a NEMA 5-20 receptacle on a 15A breaker. Otherwise, you draw too much and blow the breaker.

So, since increasing load increases heat in a circuit, which increases resistance, which increases load, which increases heat, etc., it seems it should be possible to detect that your current draw is going up at an unexpected or unsafe rate and adjust the circuitry to draw less automatically. After all, doesn't increased resistance result is decreased voltage, which is easily detectable?

Comment: What part of the circuit exactly do you expect to heat up? The house's wiring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the scenario you describe (wiring heating up so much that it causes a measurable increase in resistance) is more commonly known as an *electrical fire*.

The wiring between a breaker panel and an outlet isn't uniform - it's not just a single perfect piece of copper. There are junction boxes, maybe a switch, potentially different types of wire, and splices along the way. Each of these elements has a different resistance, and connections in particular have greatly varying resistance. The parts of the circuit with the highest resistance per unit length will heat up the most, which usually are the splices between individual wires. Note that these points in the circuit only account for a small fraction of the total resistance - they have small absolute resistance, but it's all concentrated on a single point, causing a lot of localized heat. The resistance of a wire might be higher, but it's spread out over a long distance, causing an overall lower temperature.

When these tiny hotspots in the circuit heat up, the total resistance of the circuit barely changes. In fact, when a splice heats up, its resistance might actually go *down* as contaminants are burnt off and the connections eventually melt and weld themselves together. It'll take a lot longer for the wires themselves to heat up enough for them to significantly change in resistance.

As a result, the junction boxes and outlet will already be on fire before your EV charger can measure any significant resistance change.

Let's run the numbers for an example:

Let's say the ambient temperature is at 300 Kelvin (27°C). You have an outlet with a total impedance of 2 Ohms (line to neutral), which is within the allowed range. Within the circuit, there's a splice with a resistance of 0.02 Ohms. The rest of the resistance is caused by a few hundred meters of wire. Due to the length of the wire, any heat generated in it is quickly dissipated and doesn't cause a significant temperature increase.

Your EV charger now slowly ramps up the current until it senses a resistance increase (caused by heating). Unfortunately, it'll never see any. The resistivity of copper is (almost) perfectly proportional to absolute temperature (PTAT). PVC ignites at 454°C (approximately 720 Kelvin), which is 2.4 times the ambient temperature. As the charger ramps up the current, the splice will start to heat up. When it reaches the autoignition temperature of PVC, its resistance will now be 0.048 Ohms instead of 0.02 Ohms, bringing the total resistance seen by the charger up from 2 Ohms to 2.028 Ohms. That's just barely more than a 1% change, and much less than the changes that a slightly loose socket might cause.

In the end, the EV is still charging happily, the circuit's resistance changed by barely more than 1%, and the house has successfully been set on fire. (In reality, the breaker would hopefully trip before this happens.)

This is the reason why breakers trip before any significant heating happens in any part of the circuit, and as a result, the resistance of the circuit doesn't (or at least shouldn't) change in any measurable way under load. You'll get bigger variations by simple changes in ambient temperature.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. A longer thicker wire can have the same resistance as a shorter thinner wire, so you can't tell the thickness with just the resistance. And a thick wire can be joined to a thin wire - then the circuit has be treated as if the whole circuit was made of thin wire - so you can't even tell by looking at the wire.

In fact, the whole circuit between the outlet and the breaker box could be made of thick wire, but if there is thin wire somewhere else on the circuit (in another outlet, downstream of that outlet) the breaker capacity is set for thin wire and it's completely undetectable.

The receptacles should stop you plugging a high-capacity device into a low-capacity circuit. That's why they have different shapes. If someone put a 20A receptacle on a 15A circuit, that's their own fault.